# Table with fixed height and header and colum width with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have a table with the following features:

- fixed header,
- fixed height (with visible scrollbars)
- 3 fixed width column (one large column and two narrow column).

I started using:

```
tbody { display:block; overflow:auto; height:100px; }
```

To get at least the fixed height but this rule squeezes the table on the left (I will provide a screenshot if necessary).

The table is contained in a Bootstrap 3 column.

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/PGEdK/

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: create a fiddle and update it

Comment: Have updated my answer. Sorry for the haste. I didn't notice that there's wasn't any scroll. You can check the current answer and let me know if that helps. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the [JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PGEdK/7/) which is working just like you have expected of. Acutally, there's no problem with your tbody style. You just need to add few more styles for your **th** and **td**. So, your final code will be something like this:

```
tr {display: block; }
th, td { width: 300px; }
tbody { display: block; height: 100px; overflow: auto;}
```

If you look at the fiddle, you will notice that  I have wrapped **th** with **tr** so that I can give proper width to th after giving display:block style to **tr**. So, if you want to target that tr which wraps th only, you can do that as well.

For demo purpose, I have wrapped the table with .tablecontainer class so that we have certain width to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Try max-height and max-width.. It sets the maximum height and width

Comment: Thanks, I tried with max-height but I got the same behaviour http://jsfiddle.net/PGEdK/2/